# Python Fabric: Skip refused SSH connections?

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I'm new to Python and Fabric, and I've modified a script that pings hosts on our LAN (to determine what machines are alive, we have a lot) to log into the hosts and list running processes back to the client. Whilst this works on servers, it seems there's other devices in the subnets that don't permit SSH logins and the connection is refused, causing Fabric to exit with a fatal error. Is there any way to make Fabric skip any host that refuses a connection?
Using

```
with settings(warn_only=True)
```

doesn't seem to help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set [this env var](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/usage/env.html#skip-bad-hosts) or also use [this flag](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/usage/fab.html#cmdoption--skip-bad-hosts). Searching the docs, if you can't find it in a heading, is best.

Comment: The links are broken now, but from the URL it looks like this refers to the `skip-bad-hosts` option. Note, this option has not been implemented in Fabric 2.x (which appears to be a rewrite), and I'm not aware of an existing solution.